# C - C file won't count correctly, it is 1 short

Tags: c, methods

I'm brand new to C and struggling with some syntax. My goal is to read through a text document in my directory and return a count it's length.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int counter (FILE* inPtr) { //Pointer to the file its reading from
   char ln[len]; \\length of file
   int counter = 0;  \\initializing file

while(fgets(ln,len,inPtr) != NULL{
    char* r;
for (r = ln; *r != '0';) {
   while (isspace(*run)) {
      r++;
 }
 if(*r == '\0') {
      break; 
}
 else {
     counter++; 
}
  r++;
}
return(counter);
}
}
```

Basically, I'm just trying to go past the spaces between words, break when we go over the length (when it runs to null), and count as we go. And then it keeps running until it points to no a space or null. I think I have the right idea by syntax is off...any advice?

Comment: when you increment counter, you also need to increment r, since you have now counted it and want to move to the next char.   If not, as soon as you hit a non space char, you will stay at it.

Comment: What is the error message? Because with the code given you have can't compile.

Comment: It's mostly syntax errors in the message. The remaining larger portion works, but it's syntax stuff. It won't compile and give a result. So that's mostly my issue. I'm mostly trying to figure out how I can make it work

Comment: Two of my errors include "expected ';' before ')' token and 'else' without previous 'if'. lastly 'expected declaration or statement at end of input'

Comment: Have fixed those errors except for problems with else. Still won't compile

Comment: @billybob 1) Comments in C don't use \\. Please post real code. 2) Look closely at `if(*r == '\0');` until you see something that doesn't belong.

Comment: The comments were just meant for here. They are not in the code. I'd assume if (*r == '\0') needs to be just =, correct? I made that change and still get the if/else error. Any advice?

Comment: Do learn to indent your code to a depth corresponding to its block nesting.  That makes program structure much easier to follow.

Comment: There are semicolons missing after `char *r` and after `r++`.

Comment: I will edit indents now in code. However, in terms of how it is set up, all blocks are accounted for when I check. I am not over/under one that is throwing an error. However, I'm sure that's part of why if/else is a pain. Will edit now.

Comment: There is an extraneous semicolon after `if(*r == '\0')`.

Comment: @billybob Do not post "*just for here*" code. Post real code, otherwise you are wasting everybody's time, and yours as well.

Comment: This is the real code, up to date with editing. This code is supposed to do as I listed in the description.

Comment: The code now compiles after fixing that extra ; in the if statement. It is compiled and works. One issue. It counts 1 less than it is supposed to. So, I do not think it is taking into account the ending or final word?

Comment: @billybob If this were the real code you'd get an error on the line where you forgot to replace `run`. Real code means copy-paste what you (try to) compile.

Comment: I was using a given framework from a textbook. All variables are now correct and compiling. I now face a different issue, but syntactically, it does what I want almost.

Comment: The code in your question can’t be compiled. Try it yourself.

Comment: I did and it works. This is part of a larger code, but this is an isolated function. My question was pertaining to the syntax in relation to what I wanted to do. The additional code is non-related functions and a main. I am asking about the integrity of the structure of this method in a logic way.

Comment: And without `main()` your ‘code’ is useless - add that - make it a [mre]

Comment: Others have helped me without it and I've gotten much further along. It's okay if you can't help, I get it. But, the question can be solved with this code.

Comment: My carriage has already turned into a pumpkin, so I can’t help you anyway You could have helped yourself by providing a complete minimal example.

Answer (score 1):

There are many syntax issues in your code:

- you include `<stdio.h>` twice
- single line comments are started with `//`, not `\\`
- the null pointer is defined as `NULL`, not `null`
- there is a missing `)` in `while(fgets(ln,len,inPtr) != null {`
- there is a spurious `;` in `if(*r == '\0'); {`
- you probably mean to test `*r != '\0'` instead of `*r != '0'` if the `for` loop.
- you should move the `return counter;` outside the body of the `while` loop.

Here is a modified, reformated and simplified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int counter(FILE *inPtr) { // Pointer to the file its reading from
    char ln[256];     // line buffer
    int counter = 0;  // number of non white space characters in file

    while (fgets(ln, sizeof(ln), inPtr) != NULL) {
        for (char *r = ln; *r != '\0'; r++) {
            if (!isspace((unsigned char)*r)) {
                counter++; 
            }
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Here is an even simpler version reading one byte at a time:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

// return number of non white space characters in file from current position
int counter(FILE *inPtr) { // Pointer to the file its reading from
    int c, counter = 0;

    while ((c = getc(inPtr)) != EOF) {
        counter += !isspace(c);
    }
    return counter;
}
```

If your purpose is to count words instead of bytes, you should modify it to skip whitespace, test if at end of line, increment the word count and skip all non whitespace bytes inside the `while` loop body:

```
// return the number of space separated words in the file
int counter(FILE *inPtr) { // Pointer to the file its reading from
    char ln[256];     // line buffer
    int counter = 0;  // number of space separated words in the file

    while (fgets(ln, sizeof(ln), inPtr) != NULL) {
        for (char *r = ln;;) {
            // skip white space before the word
            while (isspace((unsigned char)*r) {
                r++;
            }
            if (*r == '\0')  // end of the line
                break;
            counter++;  // count the word
            // skip the word
            while (*r != '\0' && !isspace((unsigned char)*r) {
                r++;
            }
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Comment: This has all been fixed. The code runs as needed. However, there is one last issue. The counter is 1 short, it is not accounting for something, potentially at the end? Can you assist?

Comment: @billybob: as coded above, it returns the number of non-whitespace bytes in the file from the current position to the end of file. Is this your intent? Note that line terminating sequences are considered white space and `EOF` is **not** a byte, nor part  of the file.

Comment: I do appreciate this. It means a lot. I do have to ask though, based on what I've provided above, can you tell me why it returns one less in the counter than it should/is expected? I can see what you did to clean it up...and I'm unable to modify mine until the first for loop (this is a provided framework skeleton). But, I'm wondering what under the hood of mine is making it one less in the return

Comment: Basically, the code needs to be inputted a test file (taken care of in another function) and it will return the word count total. That's all it needs.

Comment: Something in my code just was weird too...now it's 6 short, not 1...must've changed something unknowingly...

Comment: Your code was counting non white space bytes, I added a modified version that counts words. Study the difference and enjoy learning C :)

Comment: Sorry last thing....so, when I run cat test.txt in my dir followed by calling this function, I get 6 less. If I just call it on my own and enter the text file after, it is 1 less. I'm confused...

Comment: @billybob: without a full program and calling sequence, it is difficult to tell what is happening.

Comment: @billybob: Sorry, I have to leave now, before my carriage turns into a pumpkin :)